# Delphi - Keep highlighted selection in RichEdit when focus is lost

Tags: delphi, trichedit

I have an TRichEdit.
When I select some text and click on another element, the selection of the selected text disappears.
Is there a way to keep this selection, also when the TRichEdit has los it's focus?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TRichEdit has a property `HideSelection` which is `True` by default.  If set to `False` then the selection will still be visible even when the TRichEdit does not have focus.

BTW: the propery `HideSelection`exists on other controls as well.  It is also very usefull on a TListView or a TTreeView when you are showing details of the selected item in the listview or treeview.

Comment: Thanks, I had in mind that there's an option, looked at the properties 3 times but it seems i've overlooked it. Ty ;)